# Construct vector field along a curve

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. I am trying to construct a (piecewise smooth) vector field $V$ along a curve $c$ that takes on prescribed values $K_{i}$ at times $t_{i}$. Say we construct V along $c|_{[t_{i},t_{i+1}]}$. I want to do the following:

Let $\tilde{K_{i}}$ and $\tilde{K_{i+1}}$ be the parallel translations of $K_{i}\in T_{c(t_{i})}M$ and $K_{i+1}\in T_{c(t_{i+1})}M$ along $c|_{[t_{i},t_{i+1}]}$. I define
$V(t)=(\frac{t}{t_{i}-t_{i+1}}+\frac{t_{i+1}}{t_{i+1}-t_{i}})\tilde{K_{i}}|_{c(t)} + (\frac{t}{t_{i+1}-t_{i}}-\frac{t_{i}}{t_{i+1}-t_{i}})\tilde{K_{i+1}}|_{c(t)}$ on $[t_{i},t_{i+1}]$. Does this seem correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways, and it depends on what other properties you wish for the vector. One way is to take small balls around $t_i$'s so that they are disjoint. On each ball $K_i$ can be extended to a vector field on that ball. Then on each ball have a smooth function with support inside these balls and $1$ at $K_i$. Now multiply your vector field with the corresponding function on each ball. Your final $V$ will be defined to equal these on the balls, and $0$ outside the balls.

Comment: @Benham. How exactly we can extend $K_i$ to a vector field in the ball ? Is it just let the vector field to have constant coefficient equal to $K_i$ ?

Comment: Yes, locally you are in $R^n$. So, you can take the constant field.

Comment: I already made such construction. Can you take a look at this one ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2419330/using-bump-function-in-coordinate-chart-to-construct-a-vector-field-v-along-a

Comment: I have the feeling that your problem is with being convinced than math rigor. If so, I would recommend writing down calculations for one specific example, like on Euclidean plane. It should allay your doubts.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. You say that there is many ways to construct such vector field. Is there any reference where i can look up one of them ? I'm using john lee's book by the way. Thanks again.

Comment: By many ways, I mean you can have those local extensions in different ways, other than the constant vector field. So you get different extensions.

Comment: All right. Thank you very much @Behnam.